# Match in two list and make a boolean column

Tags: text-processing

I have two list, the first list contain all the names

```
$ cat file1.txt
dog_02
dog_01
dog_20
dog_22
dog_23
dog_24
```

And my second list have some names from the first

```
$ cat file2.txt
dog_01
dog_23
dog_24
```

I would like to make a pairing between the two list and and obtain a boolean output

```
dog_02 
dog_01 dog_01
dog_20
dog_22
dog_23 dog_23
dog_24 dog_24
```

if (empty) {print "0"}
else {print "1"}
; done > boolean_output.txt

```
$ cat boolean_output.txt

dog_02   0
dog_01   1
dog_20   0
dog_22   0
dog_23   1
dog_24   1
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Look into `comm`.

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]; next }{ printf "%s\t%d\n",$1,($1 in a) }' file2.txt file1.txt > boolean_output.txt
```

- `{ a[$1]; next }` - capturing all values from the 1st input file, i.e. `file2.txt`
- `($1 in a)` - the crucial condition to check for matched *names* while processing the 2nd input file `file1.txt`

---

The final `boolean_output.txt` contents:

```
dog_02  0
dog_01  1
dog_20  0
dog_22  0
dog_23  1
dog_24  1
```

Comment: @IrvingElPelofinoLopez, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [RomanPerekhrest's answer](/a/404786/72456), but in different way as it will result **0** for the names if unique only in file2 too, plus this is order independent of the files for input to `awk`, so this will work for N number of input files which the purpose is Unique Names will result with **0** and duplicated ones will result with **1** in mean.

```
awk '{s[$1]=s[$1]?"1":"0"} END{for (x in s) print x,s[x]}' file*
```